# Can mxGraph (JS) display a decision tree?

Tags: mxgraph

We are building a decision tree using mxGraph.
We are looking to display a heirarchy of Vertexes, each having a YES and a NO.
We would like the YES node to link to the WEST (right of the parent) and the NO node to be drawn underneath (SOUTH).

We would like to use the HeirarchicalLayout as then we dont need to render the coordinates ourselves when adding new nodes..

I have looked into creating a custom layout but this seems like overkill.

Is there a way to display a layout with both a WEST and SOUTH orientation based on the CellType being rendered?

Thanks in advance for your time.